# Integration between SignalR and WebAPI

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I have a WebAPI server with integrated SignalR Hubs.

The problem it is in the integration between both components and efficiently call the clients interested on a given item that was updated through REST with the least overhead possible on the Controller side.

I have read about [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), or Publish Subscriber Patterns but they don't seem the right fit for this problem.

From the documentation examples, the background tasks seem to atempt to preserve order which is not required, in fact, it is desired to allow multiple requests to be handled concurrently, as efficiently as possible.

With this in mind, I created this third component called MappingComponent that is being called through a new Task.

It is important to design the Controller in a way that he spends the least amount of work "raising the events" possible. Exceptions should be (i believe) handled within the MappingComponent.

What would be a better approach/design pattern that the following implementation, to avoid using Task.Run?

ApiController

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ItemController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MappingComponent mappingComponent;
    private readonly IDataContext dataContext;

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Item>> PostItem(ItemDTO itemDTO)
    {
        await dataContext.Items.AddAsync(item);
        (...)

        _ = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await mappingComponent.NotifyOnItemAdd(item);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
        });

        return CreatedAtAction("Get", new { id = item.Id }, item);
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}", Name = "Delete")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        var item = await dataContext.Items.FindAsync(id);
        (...)
    
        _ = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await mappingComponent.NotifyOnItemDelete(item);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
        });

        return NoContent();
    }

    [HttpPatch("{id}", Name = "Patch")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Patch(int id,
            [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<Item> itemToPatch)
    {
        var item = await dataContext.Items.FindAsync(id);
        (...)

        _ = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await mappingComponent.NotifyOnItemEdit(item);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
        });

        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status202Accepted);
    }

}
```

SignalR Hub

```
public class BroadcastHub : Hub<IHubClient>
{
    private readonly MappingComponent mappingComponent;

    public BroadcastHub(MappingComponent mappingComponent)
    {
        this.mappingComponent = mappingComponent;
    }

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        mappingComponent.OnConnected(Context.User.Identity.Name, Context.ConnectionId));
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync()
    {
        mappingComponent.OnDisconnected(Context.User.Identity.Name, Context.ConnectionId));
        return base.OnDisconnectedAsync();
    }

    public void Subscribe(string itemQuery)
    {
        mappingComponent.SubscribeConnection(Context.User.Identity.Name, Context.ConnectionId, itemQuery));
    }

    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
        mappingComponent.UnsubscribeConnection(Context.ConnectionId));
    }
}
```

"MappingComponent" being registered as singleton on startup

```
public class MappingComponent
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory;
    private readonly IHubContext<BroadcastHub, IHubClient> _hubContext;
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, User> Users = new(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<string>> ItemConnection = new();
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<int>> ConnectionItem = new();
    public MappingComponent(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, IHubContext<BroadcastHub, IHubClient> hubContext)
    {
        //this.dataContext = dataContext;
        this._hubContext = hubContext;
        this.scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    internal void OnConnected(string userName, string connectionId){(...)}
    internal void OnDisconnected(string userName, string connectionId){(...)}
    internal void SubscribeConnection(string userName, string connectionId, string query){(...)}
    internal void UnsubscribeConnection(string connectionId){(...)}

    internal async Task NotifyOnItemAdd(Item item)
    {
        List<string> interestedConnections = new();
        (...)
        //Example containing locks
        lock()
        {
            //There is a need to acess EF database
            using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var dataContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDataContext>()
                await dataContext.Items.(...)
                interestedConnections = ...
            }
        }
        await _hubContext.Clients.Clients(interestedConnections).BroadcastItem(item);
    }

    internal async Task NotifyOnItemEdit(Item item)
    {
        List<string> interestedConnections = new();
        (...)
        await _hubContext.Clients.Clients(interestedConnections).BroadcastItem(item);
    }

    internal async Task NotifyOnItemDelete(Item item)
    {
        List<string> interestedConnections = new();
        (...)
        await _hubContext.Clients.Clients(interestedConnections).BroadcastAllItems();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use a datastore like Cosmos DB that publishes changes, you can achieve this by subscribing to that feed and sending notifications out-of-band, so there would be nothing in the controller concerned with notifications. Otherwise, I'd look at a queue mechanism to add the event to for background handling, either in memory or using something like Azure Service Bus or Event Grid.

Comment: An example of doing such real-time updates is discussed here: https://whally.com/blog/how-it-was-made

Comment: @NoahStahl where I can read more about cosmosDb database change feed? Is it native from cosmosDb?

Comment: Microsoft has good docs and examples, and lots of articles on the web